# "Additional Drivers" program crash help on 12.04?

Tags: drivers, 12.04

When I select the "Additional Drivers" program, it searches for available drivers but becomes unresponsive shortly after. I tried closing it, to try again, but now it just blinks 3 times when I select it. Any ideas to work around this? I'm unsure if there's a driver I need. My network connection seems fine, though.

Edit: When I use the command `jockey-gtk`, I get an error message that ends with:

```
Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus
security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection
was broken.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try starting it from a terminal: `jockey-gtk`. See if it displays any error regarding the crash.

Alternatively there is `jockey-text` if the graphical version would fail.

In case of problems you'd probably want to read the backend debug log (`/var/log/jockey.log`). Try this:

- In a terminal window type `tail -f /var/log/jockey.log`
- Press a few <kbd>Enter</kbd>s in the same window to separate the new output from the old lines.
- Now start the *"Additional Drivers"* utility. The terminal window should start to log debug messages as the driver check is carried out.
- The last few lines might contain information about what is going wrong.

(Be warned there will be quite a couple of lines.)

There is a related Launchpad bug [#912236](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/912236) ([#864572](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/864572)) confirming your error message:

> Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply,
>   the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout
>   expired, or the network connection was broken.

But no solution so far.

Comment: `jockey-gtk` output: `Possible causes include: the remote  application did not send a reply, the message bus security  policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or   the network connection was broken.`

Comment: `jockey-text` had the same error.

Comment: First I'd check the network connection. Your `jockey-backend` might also be "confused", but the easiest way to restart it AFAIK is to reboot the system. (I'm no expert on this.) If you do not want to do that, I can give you the commands to kill and start the backend process, although that is a bit dangerous.

Comment: My network connection seems fine. I don't really know what my `jockey-backend` is. (I'm new)

Wow. So, I tried rebooting, and my screen froze before it was even shut down completely. I had to hold the power button down and boot back up. The program is still unresponsive, too.

Comment: Also, is it safe to go open "system monitor" and end the `jockey-gtk` process? I can't close it for some reason.

Comment: Considering it is already unresponsive I'd say that's ok. But I don't think that will solve your problem. As a test I started and killed the program a few times, and did not experience any negative consequences (apart from the backend part being left in memory, but at the next jockey-gtk restart it automatically closed).

Comment: @Jiskya Please put all this information in the question itself so it's not buried in the comments, it'll make it easier for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get jockey working either, no matter what i tried. However i did find a workaround. If you haven't already, install the synaptic package manager from the software center. From synaptic you can search for the driver you are trying to install and install through there.

The only downside is you have to know the name of the driver you are looking for, but some googling should be able to answer that for you.